# Parse json object with another json object in string format stored in one of the properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I think I have quite a unique problem here, where the developer of an API I need to utilize did something I don't quite understand. Yet I have to deal with it.

It is probably the best to explain the problem by showing an example:

```
{
    "type": "type-A",
    "value": "{'propA': 'type-A specific element', 'propA2': 'another typeA specific element'}"
}
```

We are dealing with a quite normal REST API, where the response is a json string - nothing too special. Because of some abstraction going on within the API, there is a `type` and a `value` field in each response. Depending on the `type`, the `value` will have differently structured content. Also nothing too special.

The problem is now that the content in the `value` field is not just a normal json object, but a string **containing** a json object. Therefore deserialization with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TargetType>(jsonString)` fails with the exception

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
>   "{'propA': 'type-A specific element', 'propA2': 'another typeA
>   specific element'}" to type 'My.Project.TargetType'.

Is there any neat built-in support in the `json.net` library I might use to counter this issue or do I have to go a manual route and fix the json or the deserialization in some other way?

---

**Edit:** to give a bit more context: The API does indeed try to abstract its interface with equal requests and responses, but I am still able to request very specific responses in my code. Therefore I make use of a generic class which contains the common properties and a generic type for the `value` like so:

```
public class Response<TValue>
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

In fact, the `type` isn't even relevant for me, because I know beforehand which `type` I will receive as response (due to my specific request). Therefore I am also able to determine the response type of `value`. My actual deserialization looks like this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<TargetType>>(jsonString)`.

Yet I did not find a neat way of parsing my `value` together with the `Response` object. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: I pretty much have the same set up, although using escaped " in the 'child' Json - I've just implemented it as two passes of deserialisation, one for the parent object, and one for the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by using a built-in which calls a method after deserialization of the object itself.

```
public class Response<TValue>
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    private string ValueString { get; set; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void DeserializeValue(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TValue>(ValueString);
    }
}
```

This allows me to simply call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<TargetType>>(json)`, where it will first deserialize the `Response` and after that the `value` property will be deserialized to `TargetType`.

Comment: That is a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, in your case you just need two steps:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string type {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
}

RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

And then, depending on the type, deserialize the other object:

```
if (r.type == "typeA")
{
    TypeA t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TypeA>(r.value);
}
```

If all types share some common properties, you might put them in an interface or base class. This will also ease reusing the deserialized class.

Comment: The messages do indeed have all common properties, only the `value` field is different. I do actually have a generic parent type where the generic type `T` should be used for the object stored in the `value` field. So I think it should be possible to trigger the deserialization of the sub-type when the parent-type is deserialized, but I'm unsure where the best place is to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: I added some more details in my question above. There is an important point I forgot originally, which is that I know the target sub-type without having to check the `type` field (because I requested the type).

Comment: Well, it works, but it is not really the solution I was aiming for, as it requires additional deserialization outside the `Response` class, as far as I can see?

Comment: If you know the type on beforehand, you can use a generic method.